Fender G-DEC stuck on boot
I haven't used the amp for about a year. But it already started to have problems some time before: while playing, all of a sudden, it would freeze up and stop working. I tried to reset it multiple times over time but that would make it work just for a little while.
Now, after some time, it completely stopped working and is stuck like shown in the pictures:


I'm not very positive on making it work again but I was hoping for someone that could understand the problem better then me.
Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Did you ask fender?

We don't have the capability to diagnose electronic or software faults remotely. You need to ask Fender or a good local tech.

I can't get my head around the idea of an amp booting up...

If a reset to factory settings doesn’t work a tech that works with Fender gear is your best option. Unfortunately digital amps in this price range are usually not cost effective to repair.
